# geom_text fails with empty tibble (sometimes)

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

After creating a figure, I want to label some points. The labeled points are the result of a filtering process, and may sometimes be empty. I want geom_text to fail gracefully when there are no points to label, (i.e., do nothing). The problem is that rather than failing gracefully, R gives me an error. The error seems entirely dependent on whether I specify hjust in the aesthetic.

This works (in the sense that it does nothing):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)


ggplot() +
  geom_text(
    data = tibble(x = numeric(),
                  y = numeric(),
                  z = integer()),
    mapping = aes(x = x,
                  y = y,
                  label = z)
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This does not:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

ggplot() +
  geom_text(
    data = tibble(x = numeric(),
                  y = numeric(),
                  z = integer()),
    mapping = aes(
      x = x,
      y = y,
      label = z,
      hjust = 0
    )
  )
#> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y and label
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Given that I don't know in advance whether the set of points to be labeled will be empty, how can I specify hjust?

Comment: Please provide your source data for both successful and unsuccessful execution.

Comment: Maybe make a function for plotting that contains an `if()` statement that only adds a `geom_text()` layer if data are present in the text dataset?

Answer (score 2):

All things mapped inside `aes` should be the same length. `numeric()` is of zero length, but `0` is of length 1. If `aes` does not vary depending on the data, set `hjust` instead of mapping it using `aes`.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_text(
    data = tibble(x = numeric(),
                  y = numeric(),
                  z = integer()),
    mapping = aes(x = x,
                  y = y,
                  label = z),
    hjust = 0)
  )
```

Note that I think it *should* be possible to include `hjust = 0`, since arguments of length 1 are supposed to be exempt from the equal length restriction, but apparently this does not work with datasets with 0 observations. This might be considered a bug (at least the error message makes little sense in this case). Regardless, there is no need here to include `hjust` inside `aes` in the first place, and I would always write it as the code above illustrates.

Comment: That's the best solution, given that hjust isn't dependent on the data in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very pretty but it seems to work. No promises, though.

Works with zero length data.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_text(
    data = tibble(x = numeric(),
                  y = numeric(),
                  z = integer()),
    mapping = aes(
      x = x,
      y = y,
      label = z,
      hjust = numeric(if(length(x)) 1 else 0)
    )
  )
```

And works with data of length greater than zero.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_text(
    data = tibble(x = numeric(1),
                  y = numeric(1),
                  z = integer(1)),
    mapping = aes(
      x = x,
      y = y,
      label = z,
      hjust = numeric(if(length(x)) 1 else 0)
    )
  )
```